# WCF service callable by other platform, and abstract class compatibility

Tags: wcf, web-services

I want to find out whether or not WCF service is **platform independent**. That is, can WCF service receive requests from other platform, like Java? If it can, Does **abstract class** in WCF work for other platform. For example, **can the code below work for other platform**?

-- This is only example

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "Service1")]
public interface IService1
{                
    [OperationContract]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Retangle))]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Square))]
    string GetShape(Shape shape);
}

    [DataContract]
    public abstract class Shape //is abstract interoperable by other language
   {    
    }

 [DataContract]
   public class Retangle:Shape
    {    
    }

[DataContract]
public class Square : Shape
{    
}
```

http://localhost:10287/Service1.svc

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A Qualified Yes, WCF if used with standard transport and message protocols like SOAP, JSON, REST, HTTP/S is highly interoperable with other platforms and languages. In practice the compatibility will vary depending on the language and platform as also the level of WS-* protocols being used if you are using SOAP.
In your specific case using KnownType works with Java and I can vouch for it as we use it in our enterprise WCF app consumed by a Java client. The Java stack we have used is [Metro](http://metro.java.net/) and the IDE is Netbeans.

You can always try with [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) which is a generic SOAP client written in Java to consume your WCF service and test if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is abstract class in WCF interoperable with other languages?

Comment: The class itself is not interoprable, but in WCF you share contract and not code. That is why you explicitly mark class with DataContract. From this a WSDL file (which represents the contract) is generated which you will give to clients to generate proxy classes. When a proxy is generated using another language it may not have a abstract class but something specific for that language. The capability of other languages should be tested but Java can handle your case.

Comment: I would suggest to build theservice, download netbeans and consume it in Java. Should not take long to do.